# mat-select-filter error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unsubscribe') at MatSelectFilterComponent.ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular-material, mat-select

I am using mat-select for dropdown. Where the options are coming from an api.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Company</mat-label>
        <mat-select
          [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
          (ngModelChange)="companyName($event)"
        >
          <mat-select-filter
            [displayMember]="'vCompanyName'"
            [array]="dataarray"
            (filteredReturn)="filteredList5 = $event"
          ></mat-select-filter>
          <mat-option
            *ngFor="let company of filteredList5"
            [value]="company.vCompanyId"
          >
            {{ company.vCompanyName }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

This is where the api is being called.

```
LoadDeviceInfo() {
    this.qmsAdjustmentService.GetDeviceInfo().subscribe((data) => {
      this.deviceInfoList = data;
      this.companyNameFiltered = _utility.getUnique(data, [
        "vCompanyId",
        "vCompanyName",
      ]);
      this.dataarray = this.companyNameFiltered;
      this.filteredList5 = this.companyNameFiltered.slice();
      console.log(this.filteredList5);
    });
  }
```

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.LoadDeviceInfo();
  }
```

mat-select-filter is filtering but throws an error saying **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unsubscribe')
at MatSelectFilterComponent.ngOnDestroy**
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Sincerely apologize. I was not aware of it since I'm new. Will keep that in mind from next time. Thank you for letting me know.